# how to add value between some value in rails console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-console

I have the following records in my database

```
[662] #<ChapterSolution:0x000055ec31cdfb40> {
            :id => 5071,
    :chapter_id => 221,
    :created_at => Tue, 19 Sep 2017 18:24:57 IST +05:30,
    :updated_at => Sat, 02 Dec 2017 10:24:53 IST +05:30,
      :question => "11",
          :part => "i",
        :answer => "See Explanation",
      :solution => "<img src='//cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/573/content.jpeg' />"

[663] #<ChapterSolution:0x000055ec31cdfb40> {
            :id => 5071,
    :chapter_id => 221,
    :created_at => Tue, 19 Sep 2017 18:24:57 IST +05:30,
    :updated_at => Sat, 02 Dec 2017 10:24:53 IST +05:30,
      :question => "11",
          :part => "i",
        :answer => "See Explanation",
      :solution => "<img src='//cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/574/content.jpeg' />"

[664] #<ChapterSolution:0x000055ec31cdfb40> {
            :id => 5071,
    :chapter_id => 221,
    :created_at => Tue, 19 Sep 2017 18:24:57 IST +05:30,
    :updated_at => Sat, 02 Dec 2017 10:24:53 IST +05:30,
      :question => "11",
          :part => "i",
        :answer => "See Explanation",
      :solution => "<img src='//cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/575/content.jpeg' />"
```

i want to add **https:** in solution value in each records, between **img src='** and **//cdn.google...** to make URL correct in each record,

however i can't figure out how to do that, any help/suggestions will appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing html tags in the database. Only store the URL i,e https:// .."

Comment: Explain more how you are storing "html" tags in the database

Comment: it is stored by csv parser, i just need to fix all links

Answer (score 1):

a cheap way is to use `gsub` and regular expressions:

```
object[:solution].gsub(/img src='\/\//,"img src='https://")
```

[gsub documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Comment: Cheap in what way? Pulling everything out of the DB and updating the records 1 by 1 is not very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching all the records and then using a regular expression in Ruby to update the records individually is not very effective.

You can actually use the [pattern matching functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html) in Postgres to perform a single UPDATE query which updates all the records at once:

```
ChapterSolution.where("solution ~* 'src=[\\''|\"]//'").update_all(
  "solution = regexp_replace(chapter_solutions.solution, '//(.*)[\\''|\"]', 'https://\\1')"
)
```

This results in:

```
irb(main):014:0> ChapterSolution.all.map(&:solution)
  ChapterSolution Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "chapter_solutions".* FROM "chapter_solutions"
=> ["<img src='https://cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/573/content.jpeg />", "<img src='https://cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/574/content.jpeg />", "<img src='https://cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/575/content.jpeg />"]
```

If you also want to strip the HTML change the regular expression:

```
ChapterSolution.where("solution ~* 'src=[\\''|\"]//'").update_all(
  "solution = regexp_replace(chapter_solutions.solution, '.*\\ssrc=[\''|\"]\/\/(.*)[\\''|\"].*', 'https://\\1')"
)
```

Comment: Your first solution worked find, but it removed ' after .jpeg, <img src='https://cdn.google.in/editor/pictures/573/content.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `solution` column data, and they has same shape like `'<img src='//cdn......'`

```
update [table name]
   set solution = substring(solution, 1, 10)||'https:'||substring(solution, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate higher level solution which avoids using regular expressions is to use a HTML parser ([Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/)) and the [URI](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) module:

```
# using .find_each loads the records in batches
ChapterSolution.find_each do |cs|
  frag = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(cs.solution)
  uri = URI.parse(frag.children.first["src"])
  uri.scheme = 'https'

  # Use this if you want to keep the HTML tag
  frag.children.first["src"] = uri.to_s
  cs.update_column(:solution, frag.to_s)

  # or this if you want to strip the HTML and only keep the URI 
  cs.update_column(:solution, uri.to_s)
end
```

The pros here over updating in the DB with a regex is that it will be able to handle much greater variations of input HTML and can ensure that the output contains a valid URI.

The con is that it will be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best way to do it, but hey it worked for me.

```
object = ChapterSolution.where("solution ~* 'src=[\\''|\"]//'")
object.each do |cs|
    cs.solution = cs.solution.split("src='").join("src='https:")
    cs.save
end
```